# Is there anything wrong with my RESTful implementation?

Tags: php, security, rest, restful-architecture

I have a server application that is providing a Restful API for clients that are written by me. This is what I am doing so far:

1). Provide a login REST URL that allows client to enter user/password (over SSL)

2). Authenticate the user on the server and return a sha1 encrypted token (user is logged in on server at this time). Token is made like sha1(user.email + date time etc).

3). Client uses the token to make requests

4). For a request to be processed on server, the token is read from the header or URL, and then compared against the logged in users sha1(user.email + date time etc).

5). If a match is made then the resource is returned else a 401 not logged in is returned.

6). After the client is done, they can log out and get rid of their local token copy.

Please tell me if this would suffice or if you think I am doing something dumb just let me know so I can improve it.

Thank You

Comment: Why compute the token from known attributes? This makes it impossible to actually invalidate a token (to end a session - required for logout).

Comment: I wouldn't say what you're doing is dumb, it is just orthogonal to REST

Comment: impossible to invalidate a session? Not too clear on that. The session ends when the user hits logout and the locally persisted token goes away.

Comment: sha1 is a hash function,  not method of encryption.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah,  this is horrible.   You are making your own session id,  and its painfully insecure.  A session id must always be a random value,  use `session_start()`.  Sure its not restful,  but its a hell of a lot more secure than the session id you are building. If your application had a sql injection vulnerability i could just pull out the data needed to build a session id for another user.   That is very insecure.

Also you probably have never heard of [OWASP a9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9-Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  In fact you should read the entire owasp top 10.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with the sha1 token approach at all, given that the user is OK with sending their credentials in the first call? Have them just send the same credentials each time and that way you'll remove the need for "logging in" and all of the session management such an approach requires.

Comment: besides making that change, any other recommendations?

Comment: @Brian: temporary token could be backed up by validating that the request headers (IP address, etc) are consistent through the life of the token? thoughts?